# How do I plot a column vector as a contour with non uniform grid points that are also column vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I have data ([link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Owokm3Xz31INJoA-BW2qsaPFFttxdaFk)) in the form given below:

**Input data format**

```
Header: 'x' 'y'  'a'  'b'
x1  , y1  , ... (data)
x2  , y2  , ... (data)
x3  , y3  , ... (data)
 :     :           :
xn-2, yn-2, ... (data)
xn-1, yn-1, ... (data)
xn  , yn  , ... (data)
```

They are non uniformly spaced grids, and I want to plot a filled contour that is colored by a, b in this case. Because of the arrangement of the points and non uniformity, I cannot use `np.meshgrid` (correct me if I am wrong). How do I plot a column vector as a contour with non uniform grid points that are also column vectors?

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('./plot_data.dat', skip_header=1, dtype = None, delimiter = '\t')
test = np.column_stack([data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,3]])
plt.imshow(test)
plt.xlim([np.min(data[:,0]), np.max(data[:,0])])
plt.ylim([np.min(data[:,1]), np.max(data[:,1])])        
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use [tricontour](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html).

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) should have no problem with non uniform 1-d domains. However, your 2-D data are irregularly distributed in the data file (see plots at the end of post). This has other issues. However, as suggested by @Thomas-Kühn, [`matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour.html) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) can handle your data (below I use `tricontourf`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y,a,b = np.loadtxt('./plot_data.dat', skiprows=1, delimiter = '\t').T
plt.tricontourf(x,y,a)
```

Result of the `a` and `b` data are on the left and right (note the black separates the two figures, and white indicates a lack of data):

[image: a on left, b on right]

Due to the sparsity of your data, a scatter plot with `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y,c=a)` may be useful too (of course with adequate `x` and `y` axes labels):

[image: scatter plot, a on left, b on right]

Or combining the filled contour plot with some representation of where the points are (combining the previous `tricontourf` with a simple `plot` of the domain:

[image: a on left and b on right]

Finally, you may like, [`matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html):

[image]